# Need simple example of SSIS Script component using Updatelistitem in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-2010

I see many examples of using UpdateListItems to update a SharePoint list but I'm unable to find an example of using that technique within an SSIS package script component. The SharePoint List Destination object is not satisfying my needs because it will not let me update the "Modified By" column.

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537013(v=office.14).aspx.
 
The MSDN web site has some very good examples of what I was trying to accomplish. I adapted them to meet my needs. Not sure why the site didn't appear when I was googling, but I'm sure it had to do with what terms I used.